# Stylus @font-face url not compiling correctly

Tags: css, font-face, stylus

I'm using a css compiler (Stylus) for the first time, and I can't get Google Web Font urls to load correctly.

This:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: light;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light') url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,500,700&subset=latin,latin-ext);
}
```

produces:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: light;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light') url("data:application/octet-stream;base64,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");
}
```

I've tried to troubleshoot, loading a character at a time, and can get part of the url to compile correctly, so this:

```
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light') url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Robot);
```

produces:

```
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light') url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Robot");
```

But as soon as I add the last 'o' to 'Roboto' it compiles as that crazy "data:application/octet-stream;base64,QGZv..." output.

I have tried other urls and get a similar result. Have also tried escaping the "=" sign. It escapes, but I still can't get it to compile correctly past 'Robot'.

For now, I'm hard coding the css file with the correct urls. Not a huge problem, but I'd like to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm 100% sure that it's not Stylus produces this behavior. You can verify it at http://tinyurl.com/hqthyml (view compiled CSS). Probably it's some plugin or maybe build tool (gulp/webpack/...) that you're using with Stylus.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you're right. Since it's a relatively easy workaround, I'm not sure I want to dive down the plugin/gulp rabbit hole. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the font you are  using from google fonmt its simple just

put this into you css file on the top 
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?       family=Roboto:400,300italic,300,400italic);

and use simple like

```
body{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

you are trying to call a html request into the css file which i understand thats why it compile this